# Delete files when done download

Tags: php, file, download, zip, php-ziparchive

How i can delete my files when will done download.
I tryed to use unlink , but not working. I don't know, maybe it deletes too quickly.

```
$zip = new ZipArchive();
$filename = "archive/myzipfiles.zip";   
if ($zip->open($filename, ZipArchive::CREATE)!==TRUE) {
    exit("cannot open <$filename>\n");
}
// Create zip
$dir = "download/pbr/1/resolution/2K/";
if (is_dir($dir)){
    if ($dh = opendir($dir)){
        while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false){
            // If file
            if (is_file($dir.$file)) {
                if($file != '' && $file != '.' && $file != '..'){     
                    if($diffuse=="true"){
                        $zip->addFile($dir."diffuse".".".$format,"diffuse".".".$format);
                    }
                    if($roughness=="true"){
                        $zip->addFile($dir."roughness".".".$format,"roughness".".".$format); 
                    }
                    $zip->addFile("download/license.txt","license.txt"); //licence
                }
            }
        }
        closedir($dh);
    }
}
$zip->close();
echo $filename;
```

Comment: Delete WHICH file(s)?

Comment: $filename = "archive/myzipfiles.zip"; 
Because the archive are there

Comment: So what is the point of making a zip fiel and then deleting it

Comment: Because several files want to be packed into one zip file, download it and then delete it from the server.

Comment: Well then you should be doing that AFTER you have uploaded it back to the user and not until. So this code is not the right place

Comment: Umm `echo $filename;` wont send the file to the users browser. It will only show them the filename on their browser

Comment: Code is working now, user can already download the files on his desktop. Here how the problem looks: generated files do not delete from my server after user downloading them. How to resolve that problem?

Comment: Since the file data is not sent to the browser until the PHP script ends, you cannot delete the file within the lifetime of the same PHP script which sends the data for download (because obviously the data would no longer exist to be downloaded). Probably the simplest thing is to create a small cron job in the background which runs at regular intervals and clears any zip files which are more than a few minutes old (this time limit is because if you simply clear the whole folder, there's a danger of deleting files which someone is still downloading).